# Stackoverflow layout problem in tab

Tags: bug, design

I am using android browser (Android 4.1) on Tab which have  1024 x 600 pixels resolution and today I found that layout is not proper, Its messing below is what I am seeing,

> [image]
> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: That other post is the exact same issue. There's no padding. It's nothing to do with negative padding...